# Making two divs appear side by side

Tags: html, css, layout

So on this page, I want to put the text next to the image, rather than below it.

http://www.helensheardfloraldesigns.co.uk/testimonials/

This is my current CSS:

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('testimonial') ):

// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('testimonial') ) : the_row(); ?>

    <div style="float:left; width:20%; background:#EEE; margin:1em;">
        <img class="testimonial-image" style="width:100%;;" src="<?php echo get_sub_field('image'); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left; width:77%;">
        <p><?php echo get_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
    </div>


<?php endwhile;

else :

// no rows found

endif;

?>
```

How would I style it so the text appears to the right of the image and not below?

Comment: 1. Don't mix `%` and `em` (you know that at some point will break ya?). 2. Don't use inline styles (It's a nightmare to maintain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there has to be room for it to float for the browser to render them side by side.

the width of the margin is not included in the 20% of the block so right now you have

1em margin + 20% width + 1em margin

if you want the next block to appear right of it you need at least 77% of the width remaining right of that first element.

Answer (score 0):

put it in a row, and set the size 70% - 30%

```
<div class="row">

...

</div>
```